# Can't get any tags when run 'git --git-dir <submodule>/.git tag'

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a submodule in my git repo A, and I want to get tags of submodule like below steps:

1. cd repo A directory,
2. run `git --git-dir <submodule>/.git tag`
3. It return nothing.

What's the steps I missed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `.git` folder for a submodule is not located in `<submodule>/`, it is located under `.git/modules` :

```
git --git-dir .git/modules/<submodule> tag
```